# WifI doesn't work under Quantal

Tags: wireless, 12.10

So, I was just installing the WiFi on my Quantal install and what I got is this:

```
Unpacking replacement bcmwl-kernel-source ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3) ...
Loading new bcmwl-5.100.82.112+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.5.0-17-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
ERROR: Module b43 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module b43legacy does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module ssb does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcm43xx does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcm80211 does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmfmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module brcmsmac does not exist in /proc/modules
ERROR: Module bcma does not exist in /proc/modules
FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
```

In 11.10 and 12.04 the installation of the "bcmwl-kernel-source" worked like a charm and I had WiFI, but on 12.10 that's (sadly) not the case.

Anyone feeling like giving me a hand? :)

Needless to say I will provide any additional info if needed :)

Comment: Can you show which packages you installed and how? I'm having the same exact problem, but when I try to do- sudo apt-get install linux-sources linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic,
I get- E: Unable to locate package linux-sources

Comment: This question should probably be a comment on the previous answer, however, try the following in a Terminal:

Comment: 'sudo apt-get update' then 'sudo apt-get install linux-source linux-headers-generic'.  I made a couple changes; one is that it is linux-source without the 's'.  The other  change (to linux-headers-generic) should make it so that if the kernel upgrades, you do not have to reinstall.  Also note that you need to be connected to the internet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to install the kernel source.  Look for linux-source in the software center.  I normally install the headers as well.  They'll be linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic in the software center.  Then try it again!

Comment: I take it that's not good :P
http://i.imgur.com/pNYtp.png
http://i.imgur.com/A91K5.png

Comment: I guess it only shows up in the Software Center after it's installed.  Let's do it from the terminal :)

Comment: In terminal do: sudo apt-get install linux-sources linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic

Comment: Thanks dude, that fixed it (well, I had to install download the packages from packages.ubuntu.com and then install the manually)